# Does Microsoft MSAL have Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant authorization support?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Does MSAL have Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant authorization[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc] support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, MSAL for Python supports ROPC flow(Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant), sample [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/ffc659091de0192754bd05d379acb8d1b4056eb8/sample/username_password_sample.py).

```
"""
The configuration file would look like this:
{
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations",
    "client_id": "your_client_id",
    "username": "your_username@your_tenant.com",
    "password": "This is a sample only. You better NOT persist your password.",
    "scope": ["User.ReadBasic.All"],
        // You can find the other permission names from this document
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference
    "endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
        // You can find more Microsoft Graph API endpoints from Graph Explorer
        // https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
}
You can then run this sample with a JSON configuration file:
    python sample.py parameters.json
"""

import sys  # For simplicity, we'll read config file from 1st CLI param sys.argv[1]
import json
import logging

import requests
import msal


# Optional logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)  # Enable DEBUG log for entire script
# logging.getLogger("msal").setLevel(logging.INFO)  # Optionally disable MSAL DEBUG logs

config = json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))

# Create a preferably long-lived app instance which maintains a token cache.
app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    config["client_id"], authority=config["authority"],
    # token_cache=...  # Default cache is in memory only.
                       # You can learn how to use SerializableTokenCache from
                       # https://msal-python.rtfd.io/en/latest/#msal.SerializableTokenCache
    )

# The pattern to acquire a token looks like this.
result = None

# Firstly, check the cache to see if this end user has signed in before
accounts = app.get_accounts(username=config["username"])
if accounts:
    logging.info("Account(s) exists in cache, probably with token too. Let's try.")
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(config["scope"], account=accounts[0])

if not result:
    logging.info("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
    # See this page for constraints of Username Password Flow.
    # https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication
    result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
        config["username"], config["password"], scopes=config["scope"])

if "access_token" in result:
    # Calling graph using the access token
    graph_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        config["endpoint"],
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},).json()
    print("Graph API call result: %s" % json.dumps(graph_data, indent=2))
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))  # You may need this when reporting a bug
    if 65001 in result.get("error_codes", []):  # Not mean to be coded programatically, but...
        # AAD requires user consent for U/P flow
        print("Visit this to consent:", app.get_authorization_request_url(config["scope"]))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, The application does not have public client flow i.e., I need to include ClientID, Client secret. To address this, I need to use ConfidentialClientApplication instead of PublicClientApplication correct?

Comment: @cj23 Yes, you are right. You can also navigate to the ‘Authentication’ blade of your AD app in the portal, set the ‘allow public client’ to true, then you can use the PublicClientApplication.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt response.Yes, I noticed. The application runs on our servers so would you recommend Client or Public? I would think Client

Comment: @cj23 If the app runs on server, I recommend you to use confidential client. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-applications

Comment: When using the above ROCP Code with ConfidentialClientApplication instead of publicclientapplication, it throws an error saying "acquire_token_by_username_password" is not an attribute. [https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication]. Any suggestions on how to use ROCP along with ConfidentialClientApplication?

Comment: @cj23 It is a new issue, I recommend you to ask it in a new post, stackoverflow avoid asking several questions in one post.

Comment: I created a new questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941384/does-microsoft-msal-resource-owner-password-credentialsropc-grant-authorizatio

Comment: It must be a configuration setting @cj23 (sorry don't know what it is) because I'm able to use `ConfidentialClientApplication` + `app.acquire_token_by_username_password` for ROPC with client id, client secret, user name, and user password.