# Does Microsoft MSAL Resource Owner Password Credentials(ROPC) Grant authorization support ClientConfidentialApplicaton class to acquire Token?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

MSAL for Python supports ROPC flow(Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant) [supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65796630/does-microsoft-msal-have-resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-authorization) token retrieve for Public Applications, Can we similarly use confidential client class in MSAL for python? The following links seem to say no--> https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication

Also, if we can use both Public & Confidential client, which is recommended from a security standpoint?

The application is a service app that runs behind the scenes on our servers and the application permissions while registering the application are given delegated permissions for security reasons & thus requiring ROPC flow to access the tokens.

Any help is appreciated

code for using PublicClientApplication class, I hoping to change the below code to use ConfidentialClientApplication but the class does not have the 'acquire_token_by_username_password' attribute and hence, I am looking for a way that uses ROPC & is ConfidentiaClientApplication.

```
"""
The configuration file would look like this:
{
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations",
    "client_id": "your_client_id",
    "username": "your_username@your_tenant.com",
    "password": "This is a sample only. You better NOT persist your password.",
    "scope": ["User.ReadBasic.All"],
        // You can find the other permission names from this document
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference
    "endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
        // You can find more Microsoft Graph API endpoints from Graph Explorer
        // https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
}
You can then run this sample with a JSON configuration file:
    python sample.py parameters.json
"""

import sys  # For simplicity, we'll read config file from 1st CLI param sys.argv[1]
import json
import logging

import requests
import msal


# Optional logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)  # Enable DEBUG log for entire script
# logging.getLogger("msal").setLevel(logging.INFO)  # Optionally disable MSAL DEBUG logs

config = json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))

# Create a preferably long-lived app instance which maintains a token cache.
app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    config["client_id"], authority=config["authority"],
    # token_cache=...  # Default cache is in memory only.
                       # You can learn how to use SerializableTokenCache from
                       # https://msal-python.rtfd.io/en/latest/#msal.SerializableTokenCache
    )

# The pattern to acquire a token looks like this.
result = None

# Firstly, check the cache to see if this end user has signed in before
accounts = app.get_accounts(username=config["username"])
if accounts:
    logging.info("Account(s) exists in cache, probably with token too. Let's try.")
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(config["scope"], account=accounts[0])

if not result:
    logging.info("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
    # See this page for constraints of Username Password Flow.
    # https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication
    result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
        config["username"], config["password"], scopes=config["scope"])

if "access_token" in result:
    # Calling graph using the access token
    graph_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        config["endpoint"],
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},).json()
    print("Graph API call result: %s" % json.dumps(graph_data, indent=2))
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))  # You may need this when reporting a bug
    if 65001 in result.get("error_codes", []):  # Not mean to be coded programatically, but...
        # AAD requires user consent for U/P flow
        print("Visit this to consent:", app.get_authorization_request_url(config["scope"]))
```

Comment: Can you provide your code? How do you use ClientConfidentialApplicaton?

Comment: @CarlZhao, I added the code for ROPC flow that uses PublicClientApplication class, What adjustments that I need to make if the application is not public?